# Find missing arguments of a calling function

Tags: r, nse

I am trying to write a function that can return which arguments from the calling function are missing.

```
find_missing_args <- function(...) {
  args <- rlang::enquos(...)
  lapply(args, rlang::is_missing)
}

func <- function(x, y, z) {
  find_missing_args(x, y, z)
}
```

However, the functionality is not as expected:

```
func(x = 1, y = 2)
```

Returns

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

It should return:

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE
```

Because `z` was not supplied in the calling function. I would also like to be able to pass which arguments I care about to `find_missing_args`, so for example:

```
find_missing_args <- function(...) {
  args <- rlang::enquos(...)
  lapply(args, rlang::is_missing)
}

func <- function(x, y, z, a, b, c) {
  find_missing_args(x, y, z)
}
```

`func(x = 1, y = 2, a = 3, b = 4)` will return:

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE
```

but ignore `a`, `b`, `c`.

UPDATE WITH ANSWER:

```
find_missing_args <- function(args) {
  supplied <- rlang::call_args_names(rlang::caller_call(n = 1))
  setdiff(args, supplied)
}

func <- function(x, y, z, a, b, d) {  
  find_missing_args(c("x","y","z"))
}

func(x = 1, y = 2)

[1] "z"
```

Interestingly,

```
find_missing_args <- function(args) {
  supplied <- rlang::call_args_names(rlang::caller_call(n = 1))
  setdiff(args, supplied)
}

func <- function(x, y, z, a, b, c) {  
  find_missing_args(c("x","y","z"))
}

func(x = 1, y = 2)

Error in c("x", "y", "z") : argument "c" is missing, with no default
```

I have not figured out why it interprets `c()` to be the argument `c` and not the function `c()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't delve into these sorts of mechanics often, so I'm not sure how robust or "idiomatic" this is, but I think this gets at what you want?

```
find_missing_args <- function(...) {
  a1 <- rlang::call_args_names(rlang::caller_call(n = 1))
  a2 <- rlang::fn_fmls_names(rlang::caller_fn(n = 1))
  setdiff(a2,a1)
}

func <- function(x, y, z) {
  find_missing_args()
}

func(x = 1,y = 2)
```

Comment: This is close to the functionality I wanted, the issue is I want to be able to select which arguments I pass to `find_missing_args`. See my addendum.

Comment: @DylanRussell In that case couldn't you simply pass them as a character vector and use that in `setdiff()` instead of the full list in `a2`?